# SQL Server conditional join with differing results columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements

I have a new app that I'm trying to figure out data for. Is for recreational vehicle ads and my idea is:

- **Advertisement** - contains `AdID` plus common items like `price`, etc.),
- **RV** - contains motorhome specific info,
- **TravelTrailer** - contains travel trailer info

If an ad joins with one or the other conditional on the `AdID` being found in one of my "secondary" tables (`traveltrailer` or `RV`) I have seen queries online like the following:

```
select
  E.EmployeeName, coalesce(s.store,o.office) as Location
from
  Employees E
left outer join
  Stores S on ...
left outer join
  Offices O on ...
```

Problem is the travel trailer and RV tables will contain some exclusive items that don't exist in the other.  As a simple example the tables could be like-

- Trailer - length, sleeping capacity
- RV - length, sleeping capacity, motor

Using the `left join` approach above sometimes I might retrieve the motor column (if it's an RV) and sometimes I might not (if it's a travel trailer). I can't figure out how to do that.

I could pass in a type (`RV` or `TravelTrailer`) and run one of two different queries based on type but I'd like to just pass in an `AdID` and get my info with that. I could also do two queries, one to get the ad info using the `AdID` and then a 2nd one based on the type that comes back from the advertisement table. I'd just like to figure out how to do this in one pull if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rethink the way you are storing the data to begin with.

Combine the RV table and TravelTrailer tables as follows:

```
products (product_id, product_type_id, product_attribute, attribute_value)
```

Where product_type_id references id on table product_types: (FK constraint)

```
product_types (id, name)
```

Ie. you might have RV be id #1 and motor homes id #2.

and where product_attribute_id references id on table product_attributes: (FK constraint)

```
product_attributes (id, name)
```

Ie. you might have weight be id #1, length be id #2, sleep capacity be id #3, etc.

This way you will not have some products in table X, some products in table Y, others in Z, etc. and you can write queries more normally. If your queries are constantly more complex than they need to be, it's usually design related.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I started with one table (Ads) then started thinking about different types of RVs. I never even thought of just breaking it down to the attributes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be this:

```
select
     Advertisement.AdId
    ,Advertisement.Price
    ,coalesce(Trailer.Length,RV.Length)   as Length
    ,coalesce(Motor,"")   as Motor
    -- other fields as desired
from Advertisement
left join Trailer on Trailer.AdID = Advertisement.AdId
left join RV      on RV.AdID      = Advertisement.AdId;
```